# Alteração de ordem das colunas Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Bom dia

Poderiam me instruir a modificar a ordem das colunas em uma tabela?
Exemplo:
Tenho a Tabela `IcmsMvaUF` com a seguinte ordem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de passar a coluna `MvaEmpresa` para ficar em primeiro, ao lado esquerdo da coluna `MvaClaFiscal`. É uma coluna PK que já tem carga de dados e, gostaria de fazer isso sem perder nenhum dado.
Já tentei fazer pelo `Design`, porém ele não permite a alteração.

Comment: Poderia postar o codigo Create da tabela?

Comment: Igor não conseguir ver o ganho que terá com isso. Poderia explicar onde quer chegar com isso?

Comment: @Marconi é por padrão das demais tabela que tem com PK a empresa. Como não me atentei a isso e fui criando a coluna, fui questionado por um colega de trabalho

Comment: @IgorCarreiro honestamente isso não tem influencia nenhuma sobre sua tabela e suas consultas

Comment: E se criar uma tabela temporaria com base em um select dessa tabela inverterndo as colulas, e então excluir essa e fazer o procedimento novamente para o nome correto da tabela?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida é o que penso.

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida Sim, não atrapalha em nada mesmo, seria mesmo pela padronização das demais criadas que tem com PK a empresa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiramente, isso não traz nenhum benefício, pois a ordem das colunas é algo somente visual para a gente, algo "cosmético", o SQL Server não se importa com isso.

A única maneira de fazer isso é recriando a tabela e isso é justamente o que Design do SQL Server faz. Provavelmente, o erro que ocorreu ao você tentar reordenar é poque deve está desativado a opção de habilitar a recriação de tabelas.

Lembrando que essa ordenação pelo Design só está disponível a partir da versão 2012, de acordo com a [documentação da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337556(v=sql.110).aspx);

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/a/1605167/4166090

Answer (score 5):

Da pra mudar pelo Design View desde que desative a opção **"Evitar salvar alterações que exijam recriação de tabela"**. Essa opção fica em Ferramentas > Opções > Designers:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso abra o designer da tabela, mude a ordem da coluna arrastando ela pra onde quer e salve as alterações.

**Importante:** Note que isso irá recriar a coluna. Ele fará um `temp_table` para manter os dados, provavelmente.

Answer (score -2):

Nas tabelas que criei no SQLDeveloper consegui alterar a ordem das colunas clicando no nome da coluna com botão direito e em seguida na opção **Colunas**.
Ao fazer isso abrirá uma nova janela chamada **Gerenciar Colunas** que tem as opções de **Reordenar, Ocultar ou Mostrar Colunas**.
Basta mover a coluna para a posição desejada e clicar em **ok**.
[Edição de posição de colunas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkZDg.jpg)

Answer (score -3):

Usa o HeidiSql que você pode editar a posição das colunas com interface gráfica amigo.

Depois você pode copiar o código de alteração do Sql no próprio Heidi.